# Restoring Large State in Apache Flink Streaming Job

Tags: hadoop-yarn, apache-flink, flink-streaming

We have a cluster running Hadoop and YARN on AWS EMR with one core and one master, each with 4 vCores, 32 GB mem, 32 GB disc. We only have one long-running YARN application, and within that, there are only one or two long-running Flink applications, each with a parallelism of 1. Checkpointing has a 10 minute interval with a minimum of 5 minutes between. We use EventTime with a window of 10 minutes and a watermark duration of 15 seconds. The state is stored in S3 through the FsStateBackend with async snapshots enabled. Exactly-Once checkpointing is enabled as well.

We have UUIDs set up for all operators but don't have HA set up for YARN or explicit max parallelism for the operators.

Currently, when restoring from a checkpoint (3GB) the processing holds at the windowing until a `org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: The assigned slot <container_id> was removed` error is thrown during the next checkpoint. I have seen that all but the operator with the largest state (which is a ProcessFunction directly after the windowing), finish checkpointing.

I know it is **strongly suggested** to use RocksDB for production, but is that mandatory for a state that most likely won't exceed 50GB?

Where would be the best place to start addressing this problem? Parallelism?

Comment: Could you share the logs of the cluster entrypoint and the TaskExecutors? If you have log aggregation activated you should be able to retrieve them via `yarn logs -applicationId <APPLICATION_ID>` after the Yarn application has been terminated.

Comment: Sure! There are a lot of them, what is the best way to share with you?

Comment: Here is the first part of each of them, though I have the full logs as well if you'd like to see them: https://pastebin.com/hKcBwD7q

Comment: Yes, the full logs would be very helpful.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much for your help. Here's a link to the full logs: https://netorg299661-my.sharepoint.com/:t:/g/personal/austin_fintechstudios_com/EdwNyzDjDaFNsB5oH00RnS4BSldg81rCJWUSzkkPUm0ZNA?e=1iWtmN

Comment: Somehow it does not open the logs if I access the links. Would it be possible to upload the logs to pastebin.com or so?